# How can I open hyperlink in the app instead of browser?

Tags: android

I have a HTML text like this:

```
val text = "Please click <a href=\"https://google.com\">here</a> for read the message. "
```

And I set to my TextView.

```
binding.textLabel.text = Html.fromHtml(text)
```

However, the link opening in browser instead of the application. I want it to open within the app. How can I do it?

Comment: Where exactly in your application should that url open?

Comment: use either an activity with webview inside it and `webview.load(url)` or use `custom Tabs Intent` from here https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/integration-guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in two steps

1. Create a webview activity
2. Send the URL as a parameter to the webview activity on the link click in `webview.loadUrl(url)

If it still persists use the `android:autoLink=""` attribute.

If you want further links to open in the webview itself use

```
ebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url != null && (url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://"))) {
            view.getContext().startActivity(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```